# Wordpress php jquery with ajax sometimes working only after refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, curl

I'm writing a plugin with ajax sending a file through Curl.
In uploading everything is working, (the Ajax call set up works , the progress bar, the gif loader)
I don't know why (not always) I have to refresh the page to get the ajax response.

It looks like WP is caching the page...

There's a lot of code I'll try to make understand with this.

Ajax config:

```
//-------------------Register/enqueue scripts and Styles
function fwd_xcg_scripts()
{
    ///...
    //Nounce  for security
    wp_localize_script('fwd_xcg_jquery_ajax_upload', 'ajaxUpload', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('_wpnonce'),
    ));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fwd_xcg_scripts');


//------------Plugin loaded
add_action('init', 'fwdXcg_init');
function fwdXcg_init()
{
    ///...

    //Ajax upload
    add_action('wp_ajax_fwdXcg_action_upl', 'ajax_fwdXcg_statusData');//Per logged
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fwdXcg_action_upl', 'ajax_fwdXcg_statusData');//Per non logged      
    add_shortcode(FWD_XCG_OUTPUT_SHORTCODE, 'fwdXcg_Output');
}
```

Jquery part.

```
...
    var data = {
                 action: ajax_action,
                 security: ajaxUpload.nonce,
                
                 
            }
            
            $('#fwdXcg_loader-icon').show();
            $('#fwdXcg_uploadSubmit').hide();
           
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
                type: 'post',
                url: ajaxUpload.ajaxurl,
                data: data,
                beforeSubmit: function() {
                $("#fwdXcg_progress-bar").width('0%');
                },
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete){ 
                    $("#fwdXcg_progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                    $("#fwdXcg_progress-bar").html('<div id="fwdXcg_progress-status">' + percentComplete +' %</div>')
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#fwdXcg_loader-icon').hide();
                    $("#fwdXcg_ajaxUploadResponse").html(response);
                    $('#fwdXcg_uploadReload').show();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                $('#fwdXcg_loader-icon').hide();
                var msg = "<p class='fwdXcgUploadFormError'>Errore ajax "+jqXHR.status+" "+ajax_action+"</p>";
                $('#fwdXcg_ajaxUploadResponse').html(msg);
                $('#fwdXcg_uploadReload').show();
                },
                
                
            }); 
            
            return false;
            }
```

Php ajax part:

```
//Ajax upload
function ajax_fwdXcg_statusData()
{
    check_ajax_referer('_wpnonce', 'security');


    $cf = "";
    if (isset($_POST['fwdXcg_uploadCf'])) {
        $cf = $_POST['fwdXcg_uploadCf'];
    }


//File da caricare
    if (isset($_FILES['fwdXcg_uploadFile'])) {


        $fileTmp = $_FILES["fwdXcg_uploadFile"]["tmp_name"];
        $upl = new fwdXcg_IO();
        $errMsg = $upl->checkFormUpload("fwdXcg_uploadFile", array("pdf", "xbrl"));//Qui i formati supportati
        if (isset($errMsg)) {
            echo "<p class='fwdXcgUploadFormError'>$errMsg</p>";
            wp_die();
        }
        $path = $_FILES["fwdXcg_uploadFile"]["name"];
        $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $destFile = "out.".$ext;
        $destFolder = FWD_XCG_DIR_UPLOAD."/";
        if (!$upl->upload($fileTmp, $destFolder, $destFile)) {
            echo "<p class='fwdXcgUploadFormError'>Errore creazione file di upload</p>".PHP_EOL;
            wp_die();
        }
        $destPath = $destFolder.$destFile;
        $api = new fwdXcg_Api();
        $ret = $api->CallFileRead($destPath);
        unlink($destPath);
        if (is_array($ret) && isset($ret["data"]) && is_array($ret["data"]) && isset($ret["data"]["res"]) && isset($ret["data"]["cf"])) {
            if ($ret["data"]["res"] == "OK") {
                if ($ret["data"]["cf"] != $cf) {
                    echo "<p class='fwdXcgUploadFormError'>Codice fiscale documento errato</p>".PHP_EOL;
                    wp_die();
                }
            } else {
                if ($ret["data"]["msg"]) {//Errore noto
                    echo "<p class='fwdXcgUploadFormError'>{$ret["data"]["msg"]}</p>".PHP_EOL;
                    wp_die();
                } else {
                    echo "<p class='fwdXcgUploadFormError'>Errore elaborazione file</p>".PHP_EOL;
                    wp_die();
                }
            }

        } else {
            if (is_string($ret)) {
                echo "<p class='fwdXcgUploadFormError'>$ret</p>".PHP_EOL;
                wp_die();
            } else {
                echo "<p class='fwdXcgUploadFormError'>Errore nel caricamento del file</p>".PHP_EOL;
                wp_die();
            }
        }


        echo "<p>Upload completato correttamente</p>".PHP_EOL;
        wp_die();
    }
    echo "<p class='fwdXcgUploadFormError'>Errore campo upload file</p>".PHP_EOL;
    wp_die();
}
```

Php html output

```
$html.="<form id=\"fwdXcg_uploadForm\" action=\"\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"  method=\"post\" >".PHP_EOL;
    $html.= "<input id=\"fwdXcg_uploadCf\" name=\"fwdXcg_uploadCf\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$cf\"   >".PHP_EOL;
    $html.= "<input id=\"fwdXcg_ajax_action\" name=\"fwdXcg_ajax_action\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"fwdXcg_action_upl\"   >".PHP_EOL;

    $html.= "<input type='hidden' name='fwdXcg_uploadType' value='crBankit' >".PHP_EOL ;
    $html.= "<p>Selezionare file: <input id=\"fwdXcg_uploadFile\" name=\"fwdXcg_uploadFile\" type=\"file\" value=\"Selezionare file\" class=\"fwdXcg_uploadFileBox\" accept=\".pdf,.xbrl\"></p>";

    $html.= "<p>Dimensione massima upload: ".intdiv(wp_max_upload_size(),1000000)." MB</p>".PHP_EOL;
    $html.= "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='fwdXcg_action' >" ;
    $html.= '<div id="fwdXcg_progress-div"><div id="fwdXcg_progress-bar"></div></div>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html.= '<div id="fwdXcg_targetLayer"></div>';

    $html.='<div id="fwdXcg_loader-icon" style="display:none;"><img src="'.FWD_XCG_IMAGES_DIR.'/loader2.gif" class="fwdXcg_loader_icon" /></div>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html.='<div id="fwdXcg_ajaxUploadResponse" ></div>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html.="<input type=\"submit\" id=\"fwdXcg_uploadSubmit\" name=\"fwdXcg_uploadSubmit\" value=\"Carica\" class=\"btnSubmit\" />".PHP_EOL;
    $html.="</form>".PHP_EOL;
```

Thanks for every suggestion.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but PHP has a syntax called [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) which allows you to write multiline strings without the need to worry about dealing with quoting and string concatenation. https://3v4l.org/QL94I.

Comment: I know but that's a snippet: in my code there are parts of HTML changing conditionally. In a variable I have more control of this.

Comment: _"I have to refresh the page to get the ajax response"_ - if you refresh the page, then I don't suppose you will actually be making AJAX request automatically again, without further user interaction? Then you could not actually be getting an "AJAX response" either though, so can you please clarify what _exactly_ happens?

Comment: To clarify: if I refresh, I get the ajax response for a while, before the page is reloaded.